# Git only push last commit and store previous in a separate branch

Tags: git, branch

I have a git-related problem. I was developing on the master branch and have 5 local commits there. From these 5 commits I only want to push the most recent one to remote. I want to store the 4 previous commits in a separate branch.

My idea was to create a new branch, go back to master und reset it, then move the last commit from the new branch to the master. Is that possible? If yes, how do I do this?

Comment: Thanks a lot- that should help. I didnt find this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create new branch, eg. `tempBranch`:

   `git checkout -b tempBranch`
2. Next, go to master and reset to state of previous 5 commits:

   `git checkout master`

   `git reset --hard idOfCommitBeforeYour5Commits`
3. Next on master branch do the cherry-pick with idOfCommitWhichYouWantToAdd:

   `git cherry-pick idOfCommitWhichYouWantToAdd`

Hint: id of commit You can find in log:
`git log`